# How to parse multiple for loops and generate new classes

Tags: parsing, io

I need to parse a for loop containing variables and inner for loops. Each for loop further contains multiple variables and for loops.
Every for loop needs to be stored in a separate DTO class with its member variables and inner for loops as List variables. In below example, we have a main class A containing multiple for loops and inner for loops and member variables. All these need to be separated in separate DTO classes with other DTO class references as lists. I tried parsing this code using several possible ways but failed to mark inner for loops.

```
Class A{
 public void a(){
    int a1;
    int a2;
    for(int b=0; b < 10; b++) {
         int b1;
         int b2;
         for(int c=0; c<10; c++){
               int c1;
               int c2;
               for(int d=0; d<10; d++){
                   int d1;
                   int d2;
               }
         }
         int b3;
         int b4;
    }

   for(int e=0; e < 10; e++) {
         int e1;
         int e2;
         int e3;
         int e4;
    }

   int a3;
   int a4;
}

Expected :
//class for main method
Class A_DTO{
  int a1;
  int a2;
  List<B_DTO> b;
  List<E_DTO> e;
  int a3;
  int a4;
}

//class for inner loop
Class B_DTO{
  int b1;
  int b2;
  List<C_DTO> c;
  int b3;
  int b4;
}

//class for inner loop
Class C_DTO{
  int c1;
  int c2;
  List<D_DTO> d;
}

//class for inner loop
Class D_DTO{
  int d1;
  int d2;
}

//class for inner loop
Class E_DTO{
  int e1;
  int e2;
  int e3;
  int e4;
}
```

Comment: What exactly your question is?

Comment: I am trying to parse a file with Class A and inner for loops as defined. I want to process the data and convert it into different classes as mentioned in the Expected Output.